# Scala play framework upgrade from 2.7.x to 2.8.x

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am trying to update an existing project built on play framework 2.7.9 to 2.8.15 and Akka 2.5.26 to 2.8.2. I'm doing so because I want to move my project to JDK 17 from JDK 8. However after upgrading the play version to 2.8.15, I'm facing over 100 errors in my API folder after compiling (mostly type mismatch and not found errors). My scala version is 2.12.17 and SBT is 1.6.2.

Is there some way to get JDK 17 to work with 2.7.9 of playframework or is there some reason why I'm getting all these errors, and can I fix these issues?

I tried fixing the errors 1 by 1 but it just keeps adding more errors to fix every time I recompile compile. I've tried sbt clean which also does nothing. I've also tried to change the versions of all the dependencies but that also did not help.

Comment: based on [play 2.8.15 release notes](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/releases/tag/2.8.15) says that jdk 17 support is experimental. before moving to jdk 17, I would try first jdk 11 (based on [play requirementes 2.8](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Requirements) says "**Java versions SE 8 through SE 11, inclusive**"), and see what happens. If there is no issues there, I would continue with a newer version for akka ([Akka 2.5 reached end-of-life 11/6/2020](https://akka.io/docs/other-releases.html)).

Comment: Also, try to share the error messages and if it is possible your library dependencies list, maybe a bit of your `build.sbt`. Without debugging details, is hard to make a good suggestion

Comment: Show us what kind of errors you get. I don't remember we faced muh trouble upgrading from 2.7.x to 2.8.x. As others suggested, don't upgrade everything at once, start with Play, then Akka, then Java (for instance).